# Cells not updating when I drag the formula down in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need the cells in `Payroll & Billing!B19:H19` to update as I drag to `B20:H20`, and so on. Please help.

```
=COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F59eQSqLQy9_JLfz4Rq12_pgksDSzdAM4tLkp45uaKE/edit#gid=2012166725","Payroll & Billing!B19:H19"), ">0)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here a bit, because the answer depends on your use case. But still.

If you need to count positive numbers row-wise from the imported range, then you could do this with `MMULT` and `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=MMULT(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    --(
        IMPORTRANGE(
          "1F59eQSqLQy9_JLfz4Rq12_pgksDSzdAM4tLkp45uaKE",
          "Payroll & Billing!B19:H20"
        ) > 0
      )
  ),
  SEQUENCE(2, 1, 1, 0)
)
```

You could just change `B19:H20` in `IMPORTRANGE` to whatever you have in the imported sheet, and change `2` in `SEQUENCE(2, 1, 1, 0)` to the corresponding number of rows.

It would be really simpler to define a Named Range in your original sheet and just import that. Say, you define a Named Range for `"Payroll & Billing!B19:H100"` (e.g. you have the data down to 100th row) and call it `My Data Range`. Then you could use this:

```
=MMULT(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    --(
        IMPORTRANGE(
          "1F59eQSqLQy9_JLfz4Rq12_pgksDSzdAM4tLkp45uaKE",
          "My Data Range"
        ) > 0
      )
  ),
  SEQUENCE(
    ROWS(
      IMPORTRANGE(
         "1F59eQSqLQy9_JLfz4Rq12_pgksDSzdAM4tLkp45uaKE",
         "My Data Range"
      )
    ), 1, 1, 0
  )
)
```

---

Old answer (sorry, did not get you right the first time):

If you just need to apply this to the 19th row starting from the column `B` you could do this like:

```
=COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("1F59eQSqLQy9_JLfz4Rq12_pgksDSzdAM4tLkp45uaKE","Payroll & Billing!B19:19"), ">0)")
```

Comment: Updated the answer.